# Unifying two implementation through an interface

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, language-agnostic

I have a simple object like this

```
  public class Book
    {
        public List Chapters { get; private set; }
        public TableOfContent BookTOC { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; private set; }
        public string Title { get; private set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string Rights { get; internal set; }
        public DateTime PublishingDate { get; internal set; }

        private IBookRepository _repository = null;

        public Book(IBookRepository bookRepository)
        {
            _repository = bookRepository;
        }

        public Book Load(string bookid)
        {
            //Load book from repository
        }

       public Chapter GetNextChapter(string chapterId)
        {
            //Load Chapter from repository
        }

    }
```

In this domain (actually anywhere in the world!), book *has* chapters and book *has* ToC. In our application, there would be two possible implementations of repository i.e. the book object may either be loaded from Xml or be loaded from database. These books are pretty large in size i.e. two-four hundred thousand chapters (This is all about book metadata, content is separate but out of question for now)

My problem is that when the book is loaded from database, I want to leverage database capabilities of querying and indexes etc. For example, in the GetNextChapter, when I am using database repository, I can locate just the specific chapter and find next of it. However in case of Xml, since I don't want to traverse xml over and over again, I would like to keep it loaded at one time initially and the cache it upstream so that I can find the next chapter just from the object itself. As you can see, these two implementations by nature are different, but at any given time we will be using only one of those. I am not able come up with a uniform interface of operations that both these implementations can follow. Let's say if I decide to have operation GetNextChapter implemented in both, then for database repository, I just need the chapter ID, whereas in the Xml repository, I need the whole book object or at least list of chapters (and even that has nothing to do with xml actually because that's just in memory filter).

Can anyone help in deciding how do I uniform these two through a single interface having two implementation? Or are they not meant to be uniformed via a single interface and deserve a separate way of implementation?

**EDIT**
To clarify further, if I add GetNextChapter method in the interface, Database implementation needs only the chapterID as parameter, whereas Xml implementation would need the book object. Similarly the LoadBook method will return full object (with chatpers and toc) for XMLImplementation (so that I don't have to traverse xml over and over) whereas it will only return partial object (without chapters and toc) in case of DatabaseImplementation (for obvious performance reasons).

So how will these two go against a single interface?

Comment: If you're going to code to a single interface, then both implementations should adhere to the same contract and return the same kind of data. Not to make things more complicated, but an interface is more than an `interface`. It's also the pre-conditions, post-conditions, and expected return values. In other words, if your XML implementation doesn't return the same data, clients will likely need to type check because you've broken Liskov's substitution principle.

Comment: Could you format the question a little bit. Now it's a wall of text. Adding some bullets, splitting some paragraphs or adding some section titles would make easier to understand,

Comment: I suppose it depends in part on how you identify the type of source (db or XML). Do you try to access it from both and then read it from whichever is found first? Do you try in sequence to access from one and then the other? I suggest you have one "book" abstraction layer and you have the two implementation for getting the book from db or XML file(s) and then a bit of glue between the lower-level and the "book" object layer.

Comment: @RubberDuck thanks for the directions, I could see what I was doing wrong. Expecting two different implementation to be consumed by client without having knowledge of their internals, which as you said, was indeed wrong, but I did not realize that. Some answers below gave me together a good view about approaching this, but your comment was indeed helpful.

Comment: @MarkH it's basically contextual, and both these modes are mutually exclusive. To give you more details, these are consumed by different type of clients one is a background process and one is active web application. Background process client does not worry about time it takes, so long as it's done, so that's where I am loading it from xml one time & cache thereafter, whereas web application needs data on the fly, so the same data is extracted (one time) from xml and stored in database, which is used by web application client.

Comment: Can't you just import the book into your database once from XML (or the other way around) and then have just a single way of working? What is the advantage for you to be this flexible in datasources for a book? In that case you would just have a ETL or import method which converts the book and that's it. You could also fix any schema issues at that point where the XML does not correspond to your data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think some of the other answers touch on this, but I will spell it out.

Constructors are not part of the Interface so you can have different ones for each repo.

```
public BookRepoXml(string xmlStringContainingAllBookData) //or a filename to the bookxml?
{
    this.cachedChapters = this.ParseXmlIntoChapterDictionary(xmlStringContainingAllBookData);
}
```

and

```
public BookRepoSql(string databaseConnectionString)
{
    this.dbConnectionIWillUseLater.Open(databaseConnectionString);
}
```

then Both repos can implement the same method

```
public Chapter GetChapterById(string id)
{
    return this.cachedChapters[id]
}
```

or

```
public Chapter GetChapterById(string id)
{
    var data = this.dbConnectionIWillUseLater.Execute("select * from chapter where..");
    return this.PopulateChapterFromData(data);
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on this a little? How is chapter-within-book identified? Or are you assuming chapter is unique among all chapters of all books? Are you suggesting that some mapping of book-to-chapter is loaded for each book?

Comment: The OP says the sql only needs id, so i assume this is a unique identifier for chapter. Looking at your answer I think ive interpreted the question a bit differently to you

Comment: Thanks Ewan. This gives me good directions, as @RubberDuck pointed above in the comments, I see that two implementation following same interface must have same input output unless we want client to be known of their internals. Additionally as you showed above, I can keep them still separate by correct use of interface. Some other answers also were helpful for me understanding how to proceed. I still have to figure out complete picture but all of them together helped me in getting to the right direction. I will accept yours at the moment.

Comment: Ew, opening database connection and parsing data in constructors.

Comment: Yeah i know, but keeps example code short

Answer (score 2):

I would decouple the three responsibilities for a repository (load book from XML, load book from a database, cache book) into three different implementations:

```
public interface BookRepository {
    Book getBookFromId(string id);
}

public sealed class XmlBookRepository : BookRepository {
    private readonly string path;

    public XmlBookRepository(string path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public Book getBookFromId(string id) {
        //open xml file from path
        //load the full book and returns it
    }
}

public sealed class DbBookRepository : BookRepository {
    private readonly string dbConn;

    public DbBookRepository(string dbConn) {
        this.dbConn = dbConn;
    }

    public Book getBookFromId(string id) {
        //query the db with the id
        //load the full book and returns it
    }
}

public sealed class CachedBookRepository : BookRepository {
    private readonly BookRepository origin;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Book> cache;

    public DbBookRepository(BookRepository origin) {
        this.origin= origin;
        this.cache = new Dictionary<>();
    }

    public Book getBookFromId(string id) {
        if(!cache.ContainsKey(id)) {
            cache.Add(id, origin.getBookFromId(id));
        }
        return cache.Get(id);
    }
}
```

With these 3 implementations you can compose either a cached xml repository:

```
new CachedBookRepository(new XmlBookRepository("data.xml"));
```

or a simple database repository:

```
new DbBookRepository("connString");
```

and as a bonus you can also create a cached db repository without any extra effort:

```
new CachedBookRepository(new DbBookRepository("connString"));
```

or if you remark that the cached xml repository is over-engineering, you can remove it in only one place without affecting anything else in your code:

```
new XmlBookRepository("data.xml");
```

Usage:

```
BookRepository br = new CachedBookRepository(new XmlBookRepository("data.xml"));
Chapter c3 = br.getBookFromId("1").getNextChapter("2"); //will read the full book and cache it
Chapter c4 = br.getBookFromId("1").getNextChapter("3); //will read from the in-memory object
```

Comment: And he exactly says he doesn't want "load the FULL book and returns it". He wants to load only piece and then do additional querying as the book is used. Sort of lazy loading.

Comment: This is a good approach in general. Worth thinking, so I will try to incorporate part of it definitely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your Book is basically a list of chapters with additional metadata and you want to add it two ways of loading through a unified interface. But depending of the persistance, the get/load operation changes.

> if I add GetNextChapter method in the interface, Database implementation needs only the chapterID as parameter, whereas Xml implementation would need the book object.

So, simply force that you need the book object. Then implement the get with either of the data (ID or chapter list) depending of the underlying repo.  A method that would get a chapter by id without book reference doesn't belong to  `Book` class, it is a seperate `Chapter` constructor/loader.

Also, it is unclear to me whether or not you want to implement `GetNextChapter` as an iterator (current chapter is inside the class, no id parameter) or a random id accessor (I'd call this GetChapterById, with id as a parameter). But I assume it is an Iterator and does belong to `Book`.

> the LoadBook method will return full object (with chatpers and toc) for XMLImplementation (so that I don't have to traverse xml over and over) whereas it will only return partial object (without chapters and toc) in case of DatabaseImplementation (for obvious performance reasons).

Partial objects don't sound very correct to me. You have several possibilities, but what I would do is make the book repository implementation support abstracted get/load operations. `BookRepository` inevitably support distincts implementations depending if it is XML or DB, so it sound logical to put the abstraction here. What would happen to your book class is that `ListChapter` would not be a field of `Book`, it would be a field of your `XMLBookRepository` only.

Answer (score -1):

> Can anyone help in deciding how do I uniform these two through a
>   single interface having two implementation? Or are they not meant to
>   be uniformed via a single interface and deserve a separate way of
>   implementation?

In short, Interface Segregation principle is important because if a certain class becomes the new hotness then one would want to use it everywhere.

Client should not be forced to use a interface if it does not need it.

Answer (score -2):

This is a perfect example for an use of interface, or if you may, a public API. Within your `Book` domain, you are dependant on an implementation of `IBookRepositoy`, to whom you will interact with via it's public API (its public methods).

Now you just need to follow the Single Responsibility Principle and Separation of Concerns in order to achieve a good design. What you want here is to have multiple implementations of `IBookRepository`, that are not known to your `Book` domain object. You could say `XMLBookRepository` and `DatabaseRepository` would be your 2 different implementations.

That being said, the implementation used in both of this repositories should stay hidden from the Book domain, as it will interacting via the public API, the `IBookRepository` interface.

Once that's on the table, you need to implement both repository in the way they are needed. Note we are talking about 2 **different** implementations; this is because, as you yourself stated:

> when I am using database repository, I can locate just the specific chapter and find next of it. However in case of Xml, since I don't want to traverse xml over and over again, I would like to keep it loaded at one time initially and the cache it upstream so that I can find the next chapter just from the object itself.

This is a clear indication that you need multiple implementation.

Comment: I am little bit confused or I should say my question was kind of misleading. (I will correct it now). I follow you upto the part of creating interface and having two different implementations. My problem is further down i.e. when I am defining interfaces, I am not able to come up with common methods because each implementation requires different parameters. See Edits for more details

Answer (score -2):

Simple. Make `Book` abstract class and implement it's loading in concrete classes.

First, I would not mix up "repository-like" methods in `Book`, but keep it only in repository.

```
public abstract class Book
{
    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; private set; }
    public TableOfContent BookTOC { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string Rights { get; internal set; }
    public DateTime PublishingDate { get; internal set; }

    public abstract Chapter GetNextChapter(string chapterId);
}


public class DBBookDepository
{
    public Book LoadBook(string identifier)
    {
        return new DBBook(this);
    }
}

public class DBBook : Book
{
    private readonly DBBookDepository _bookRepo;

    public DBBook(DBBookDepository bookRepo)
    {
        _bookRepo = bookRepo;

        // load stuff from DB
    }

    public override Chapter GetNextChapter(string chapterId)
    {
        // either do SQL command or call repository
    }
}

public class XmlBookRepository
{
    public Book LoadBook(string path)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(path);
        return new XmlBook(path, xmlDocument);
    }
}

public class XmlBook : Book
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly XmlDocument _xml;

    public XmlBook(string path, XmlDocument xml)
    {
        _path = path;
        _xml = xml;

        // load some other stuff
    }

    public override Chapter GetNextChapter(string chapterId)
    {
        // load chapter from xml
    }
}
```

This is not exact solution. For example you can load stuff in repository and then pass it into concrete objects instead of doing that in constructor. Also, it seems that you cannot have generic IBookRepository, because different repos will load books based on different parameters (eg. DB ID vs. path to xml).

Also, if you want to have "chapter browsing" logic, then extracting that into it's own object might be good idea. Similar to what iterators do.

Comment: Why should a `Book` know anything about a XML document or (even worse) a Database? I don't want a database, I want my `Book`.

Comment: @DavidPacker And that is exactly what you get. Did you even read my answer?

Comment: No, you do not. For example your DbBook knows about the repository, which it should not.

Comment: @DavidPacker Well, good thing that is DbBook and not Book. Book knows absolutely nothing about database or XML. And code using Book has no idea either. That is true power of abstraction.

Comment: I am fairly familiar with abstraction, but your approach smells of Active Record, which is a pattern frowned upon. First you have a `Book` which knows about a repository, the next thing you have is a `Save()` method on the `Book` class. And even if you do not, which is good, when you will want to work with a `Book`, you will have to pass a `Book` class to some other class as a dependency and a repository on top of that, so you can update the modified `Book` object (even though some repository is already passed through the `Book` object). Why would you want that?

Comment: @DavidPacker My implementation is basically manual implementation of what ORMs like nHibernate or EF do automatically. Ever wondered why properties for db entities need to be virtual? Because the framework creates derived type and overrides all the methods for interception. And do you need Save method on every entity object you pass to ORM? Of course no. And there is absolutely no need to pass repository around with book.

Comment: Unless I am seeing something else, you are actually injecting either the db repository or the source xml file as a constructor aggregation to your book classes. You claim *there is absolutely no need to pass repository around with book*, meanwhile your book has the repository as a dependency. How is that different? in order to construct the object graph for a `Book` object you need a `Repository`. If you use a `Book`, you (internally by the book) use a repository, even if you don't need the repo at all. You pass more code than you actually need.

Comment: @DavidPacker First. You have to differentiate between Book and DbBook. Yet, you are talking about them as if they were same thing. Those are two separate classes, with different dependencies. Book itself doesn't depend on any repository. It is "open for extension" in that regard. DbBook does depend on repository, but that is irrelevant for code that used Book. Thus it is false to claim that code that uses Book depends on repository because it's children depend on repository. Can you show me code how would code using Book depend on repository?

Comment: Your Book class is abstract. If I saw something like that in a code, I would probably ask, why would a domain model be an abstract class, think it is probably because it has some dependencies I should not really care about. Which would lead to another question, why would my domain model have a dependency I should not care about? If something is hidden inside a factory, be it, but my domain makes my business work. I am standing behind my opinion that your domain `Book` model smells of active record, which I do not like. If you like it, then I guess it is fine. We all have our own preferences.

Comment: @DavidPacker Lets look at it differently. What if there was IBookPersistenceService, that would be defined in domain. Non-abstract Book would need this service to work. Then, there would be DbPersistenceService in database module. Then the DbPersistenceService would be initialized when loading Book from database and composed with Book, so book can call it. Would you agree this design is good? Does it smell like Active Record? If you think this is good, then how is it different from same interface as part of abstract Book class?

Comment: You are then most likely introducing anemic models into your application, passing these models around your application and have services do all the work. If you have services to manipulate data of a class, why not put a method into the manipulated class itself to perform the business logic? Which brings us back, once your class contains business logic, it should not contain persistence logic and vice versa.